# How to implement an eventually repeating list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, wolfram-mathematica, infinite

I can see how [cycle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle) can be used to implement a repeating list (eg [0,9,0,9,...], the decimal expansion of 10/11), but how could one implement one that has some initial elements before it settles down to a repeating pattern (eg [3,1,4,2,8,5,7,1,4,2,8,5,7,...], the decimal expansion of 22/7)? I'd like such a structure to work well with fold etc.

My specific interest is representing decimals and continued fractions where the list just contains digits or numbers, respectively, but also lists with more general types are of interest eg pairs of numbers.

Mathematica implements recurring fractions ([RealDigits](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html?q=RealDigits) and [FromDigits](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html)) and recurring continued fractions ([ContinuedFraction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuedFraction.html) and [FromContinuedFraction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromContinuedFraction.html)):

```
ContinuedFraction[Sqrt[13]] = {3,{1,1,1,1,6}}
```

and

```
RealDigits[22/7] = {{3,{1,2,8,5,7}},1}
```

A similar question is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21998/building-a-continued-fraction but the results seem very adhoc and I'm hoping for something more clean in Haskell.

Comment: This is slightly off the (literal) main topic here, but you might also be interested in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJQgYBQFtSE) about implementing exact real (computable) number arithmetic in Haskell using a continued fraction representation (as well as another technique).

Answer (score 5):

Why not just prepend something to the result of `cycle`?

```
3 : cycle [1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7]
```

Whereas a “circular” linked list is one where the tail points back to the head, this is a linked list with a cycle that points into the middle of the list, like so:

```
let x = [1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7] ++ x in 3 : x
3 : (let x = 1 : 4 : 2 : 8 : 5 : 7 : x in x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general function. It will take any real number from any function.
This, of course, only does two parts.
I'm sure you can do better. This is just a starter. I use show to process the number as a string because Haskell is so picky about mixing floating/non-floating types.

```
c2l d = splitAt 1 [read [u] :: Int| u<-(tail.tail.show $ d/10)]
```

Execute as

```
c2l (22/7)
```

([3],[1,4,2,8,5,7,1,4,2,8,5,7,1,4,3])

Or

```
c2l (sqrt 13)
```

([3],[6,0,5,5,5,1,2,7,5,4,6,3,9,8,9])

Also the Haskell Math library is most wonderful. There is Computer Algebra, fix points, set theory, analysis, linear algebra (!) and abstract algebra.

Take the `splitAt 1` out to have just a linear list.